# How do I post all values from all select elements in a single form action?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm developing a typical dating site like male/female seeks male/female between ages x and y in all or a selected province. For this I have the following code:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('password/listmatches' ) ?>"  method="post" >
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>I am a:</span>  
        <select id="gender1" >
            <option value="male1" >Male</option>
            <option value="female1" selected="selected">Female</option>
        </select>  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Seeking a:</span>  
        <select id="gender2">
            <option value="male2" >Male</option>
            <option value="female2" selected="selected">Female</option>
        </select>  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Age:</span>  
        <select id="age1" >
            <option value="eighteen" selected="selected">18</option>
            <option value="nineteen">19</option>
            <option value="twenty">20</option>
            <option value="twentyone">21</option>

        </select>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>To:</span>  
        <select id="age2" >
            <option value="hunderd" selected="selected">100</option>
            <option value="ninetynine" >99</option>
            <option value="eightyeight" >88</option>
        </select>  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Location:</span>  
        <select id="provinces" >
            <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
            <option value="ec">Eastern Cape</option>
            <option value="nc">Northern Cape</option>
            <option value="wc">Western Cape</option>
            <option value="fs">Free State</option>
            <option value="gp">Gauteng</option>  
            <option value="kzn">Kzn</option>
            <option value="lim">Limpopo</option>
            <option value="mpu">Mpumulanga</option>  
            <option value="nw">North West</option>  
        </select>  
    </td>  
    <td><input class='submit_img' type="image" src="/images/rainbow/gobuttonbluesmall.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</form>
```

How can I post whatever is selected(if any) to:  url_for('password/listmatches' ?
I cannot do a onChange because user might just keep the selection as per the form and hit the go button. I need to produce a list based upon what was selected on a next form.

Any advise please?
Thank you

Comment: I am a little confused, are you trying to post all values every time any of the select elements are changed?

Comment: For starters, you should give `name` attributes to your `<select>` elements.

Comment: nope... post after all values are selected and i hit the go button :)

will give names to select tags thank you

Comment: when i select values and hit go, on the next form i did a print_r($_POST) and got what looks like to be the correct values: 

    Array ( [gender1] => male1 [gender2] => male2 [age1] => twentyone [age2] => eightyeight [provinces] => wc [x] => 22 [y] => 17 )

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a form is submitted, only form controls that have a name will actually be sent to the server.  Your select controls don't have a name, so they don't get posted.

```
    <select  name="gender1" id="gender1" >
```

When submitted, the values will be available in the $_POST array.